# How can I express a logistic regression equation

Tags: regression, logistic

I see a lot of examples of linear regression like this:

y = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4 + (a3*a5)*x5 + (a4*a5)*x6.

But I would like to write something similar for a logistic regression. I am not interested in being mathematically precise because the message I want to convey is simply:

the outcome (is a function of) predictor-a, predictor-b, etc

For example,

Diabetes Mellitus (is a function of) age, sex, HbA1c, hypertension, ischemic heart disease, chronic kidney disease, socio-economic status.

Is there a symbol typically employed in these situations for the relationship between the outcome (the thing you are predicting) and the predictor variables?

Thanks

Comment: It may be more that the chance/probability/odds/risk of Diabetes Mellitus varies with age, sex, ....

Answer (score 1):

logistic regression is a specific part of generalised linear models (GLM) where you can found more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model.

As for logistic regression,
let's say that you have y as a response which follows bernoyli(p), then

log(p/(1-p)) = X_{i1}*beta_{1} + .... + X_{in}*beta_{n}

where you should estimate betas and X_{i1} could be the age of the person 1 and so one as for the other variables.

Hope this is helpful!